# Swift UNNotification - Repeat Interval after Fire Date

Tags: ios, swift, localnotification, unnotificationtrigger

I'm sending a local notification to the user with a UNUserNotification. I want to first send a notification at a starting time I'm calculating from a Time Picker. After this first notification, I want to send a reminder every 15 minutes. Is there any way to set the Trigger for a Calendar and a time interval?

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "HH"
    let hour = dateFormatter.string(from: _notificationTime)

    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "mm"
    let minutes = dateFormatter.string(from: _notificationTime)

    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = Int(hour)
    dateComponents.minute = Int(minutes)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.body = "Hi " + settings.username + ".\nHast du deine Pille schon genommen?"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "takePill"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "takePill"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DontForget", ofType: "PNG") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "DontForget", url: url, options: nil)
            content.attachments = [attachment]
        } catch {
            print("The attachment was not loaded.")
        }
    }

    let pillTakenAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "pillTakenAction", title: "Pille eingenommen", options: [])
    let pillTakenCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "pillTakenCategory", actions: [pillTakenAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    center.setNotificationCategories([pillTakenCategory])

    content.categoryIdentifier = "pillTakenCategory"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

`UNNotificationTrigger` has a property `repeats` which determine if the the notification should be repeated or not. By setting that property to true, you specify that the notification needs to be repeated at the given date.

In your code above :

```
var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    dateComponents.hour = Int(hour)
    dateComponents.minute = Int(minutes)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
```

You have specified the property as true, which will repeat the notification at the particular time `dateComponents`.

To achieve this you can use `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`. First, schedule the `UNCalanderNotificationTrigger` at your specified time. When this notification gets called, in the `userNotificationCenter(_ center:, didReceive response:, withCompletionHandler completionHandler:)` function you can schedule a `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` to repeat every 15 minutes.

Your code will look like

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: (15*60), repeats: true)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.body = "Hi " + settings.username + ".\nHast du deine Pille schon genommen?"
    content.categoryIdentifier = "takePill"
    content.userInfo = ["customData": "takePill"]
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DontForget", ofType: "PNG") {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        do {
            let attachment = try UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "DontForget", url: url, options: nil)
            content.attachments = [attachment]
        } catch {
            print("The attachment was not loaded.")
        }
    }

    let pillTakenAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: "pillTakenAction", title: "Pille eingenommen", options: [])
    let pillTakenCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: "pillTakenCategory", actions: [pillTakenAction], intentIdentifiers: [], options: [])

    center.setNotificationCategories([pillTakenCategory])

    content.categoryIdentifier = "pillTakenCategory"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    center.add(request)
}
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: This will only work if the user interacts with the notification. Sadly there is no way to do this without the app being in the foreground or user interaction.